# location.getspeed() update

Tags: android, gps, location

I have a litte problem. I located a `location.getSpeed()` method on the `onLocationChanged()` method, and `.getSpeed()` usually doesn't update/change to 0km/h when I stay in same place.

Where should I locate a `location.getGpeed()` method, that the update showed 0km/h when I stay in place?

And another question. This is my `locationListener`:

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() 
    {public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {     
    boolean var = false;
    float distance;

        if (firstRun) { distance=0; firstRun=false; }
        else
        distance = location.distanceTo (startLocation);
        Tspeed.setText("0km/h");


        if (location.getSpeed()!=0) 
        {
            Tspeed.setText(""+(location.getSpeed()*3600/1000 +"km/h")); 
        }
        else
        {
            Tspeed.setText("0km/h");
        }


        sAllDistance += distance;  // 
        startLocation=location;
        Tdistance.setText(""+(int)SAllDistance+" m");

    }
```

The problem is: when the `LocationManager` get the fix, the first `AllDistance` returned from `location.distanceTo()` is ±50 meters.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, GPS wont give exact information all the time. Even if you stay at same place, some times, latitude and longitude vary a little bit. I think it depends on `minTime` and `minDistance` you provide to `requestLocationUpdates(...)` method.

Anyway, once try to change these values like below.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
             1000L(minTime), 2000.0f(minDistance), myLocationListener);
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit:**

One more thing you can do is, according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#hasSpeed%28%29), `location.hasSpeed()` returns `true` if this fix contains speed information, `false` otherwise. When you stay at same place, it returns `false` I guess.

Based on this, you can do something like setting value for `textView` etc.

I have not tried but you can try once.

Comment: Ok i have changed this, and I added if (location.hasSpeed()) {
    if (location.getSpeed() != 0) {... But location.getSpeed() still sometimes show speed>0 when I stay in place

Comment: @KrystianBersztolc that's what I experienced and mentioned in my answer `GPS won't give exact information all the time` :)

Answer (score 1):

There are continuous, varying errors in GPS location fixes, due to things like atmosphere, satellite geometry, nearby buildings, etc.

The best you can do if you're trying to determine whether the GPS receiver is stationary or not is to check if the speed is below some credible threshold (e.g. 1kph).

You can do things like digitally filtering the speed value e.g.below is a simple adjustable low-pass filter that smooths out changes in the speed... put in a low value (e.g. 3) and the output will be quite responsive to changes in the input, put in a high value (e.g. 10) and the output becomes heavily smoothed.

```
    /**
     * Simple recursive filter
     *
     * @param prev Previous value of filter
     * @param curr New input value into filter
     * @return New filtered value
     *
     */
    private float filter(final float prev, final float curr, final int ratio) {
      // If first time through, initialise digital filter with current values
      if (Float.isNaN(prev))
        return curr;
      // If current value is invalid, return previous filtered value
      if (Float.isNaN(curr))
        return prev;
      // Calculate new filtered value
      return (float) (curr / ratio + prev * (1.0 - 1.0 / ratio));
    }

    filtSpeed = filter(filtSpeed, speed, 3);
```