# getLastKnownLocation only updates when position changes ~50 m. Why?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

In using the `getLastKnownLocation()` method of `LocationManager`, I noticed that the position which it obtains only changes if I move approximately 50 m.

This is despite the fact that `GPS` visibility is high and positioning error should be on the order of 5 m in the areas where I tested it. I was wondering if there is any "distance change" constraint built into `getLastKnownLocation()`, such that it only updates its saved location if the position changes by a certain amount [much like you can place a distance constraint on `requestLocationUpdates()`].

If so, does anyone know what that distance constraint is exactly?

Thanks!

Comment: its better to use LocationListener for fetching location

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900097/location-getspeed-update/11900757#11900757.

Comment: Wouldn't it be awesome if your battery was completely drained because some programmer at google decided the last know location should be exact?

Comment: @Android Coder: I understand that LocationListener is normally used to get location updates, but there are other design reasons I have for choosing getLastKnownLocation(). The main reason is because I want to ensure that my application receives *some* location at a regular interval, regardless of whether a provider is available or not. LocationListener will not give me that.

Comment: @Warpzit: My question is concerned with the granularity of getLastKnownLocation(), not its energy usage. Regardless of whether having a distance change constraint is a good design choice or not and whether or not it has an effect on battery usage, I would like to understand better how this method works.

Answer (score 3):

The `getLastKnownLocation()` method will only return the location of the last GPS fix - regardless of whether it was obtained by your application or a third party application. It doesn't return your current location and it doesn't change if you move approximately 50 meters - at least not if no other applications are using the GPS.

It should be used to give an approximated location of the user or as a "placeholder" until fresh data is obtained.

See this blog post for more details on this:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Reto Meier, a member of the Android developers team, also gave [a speech at Google I/O](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twmuBbC_oB8) last year in which he talked about the use of location services, including `getLastKnownLocation()`.